# Run website on Google Cloud with more than 6.5GB per vCPU

Tags: memory, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm running a website that has high memory requirements because it implements a machine learning model.  I suspect 8GB will be enough, but could need a little more.

Google App Engine standard and Cloud Run limit you to 2GB per instance. GAE flexible limits you to 6.5GB per vCPU.

Is there an option on Google Cloud to run a website with more memory than this?

With AWS Elastic beanstalk it is easy to just select a large or xlarge instance to get the needed memory.

Answer (score 3):

2 vCPUs, 8 GB RAM. 6.5 GB per vCPU is a [documented restriction](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#cpu).

GCP instances in general have options for higher memory. But App Engine doesn't go that high for RAM per CPU.

Comment: Right, but are there non-GAE options that I should consider?  I suspect I could use a kubernetes cluster but I hope there is a less complex option.

Comment: You specified App Engine, I specified an instance size for that. If you want something other than App Engine, try that instead.